# How to add addition condition to ransack after submiiting the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a book library rails app using ransack. Basically, after searching for book title and category. I want to have additional condition like in Amazon page. So I use link_to with parameter of ransack. But the problem is that the page will render the result will only base on the parameter which I sent in link_to. Is there a way that allow me to insert a condition in current search session of ransack. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to merge the new condition into the existing filter and pass that hash to the path helper.

Something like this:

```
books_path(q: params[:q].merge(additional_filter_eq: value))
```

Comment: Can you please make example with the code. So I have existing filter in my application.html.erb. And have my new condition through link_to in other view. So how can I merge it. Thanks!

Comment: Please look at my edit